# Spring InitializingBean does not work with CDI

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, cdi

When the class annotated with: @Component or @Service or @Repository (Spring annotations) `InitializingBean` is working fine and `afterPropertiesSet()` method is called, if I have a class which is annotated with `@Named` - CDI annotation, method `afterPropertiesSet()` never gets called. Shouldn't Spring provide full support of CDI annotations? All dependency injections are working fine with `@Inject` it is just InitializingBean which is not working. Could someone explain way is it so?

Answer (score 2):

According to Spring Documentation:

> It is recommended that you do not use the InitializingBean interface
>   because it unnecessarily couples the code to Spring. Alternatively,
>   use the @PostConstruct annotation

Comment: This doesn't answer my question. I am not looking for alternatives, I am asking why it is not supported.

Answer (score 2):

Spring supports JSR 330, which is `@Inject`, `@Named`, `@Scope`, `@Qualifier`, `@Provider` (http://jcp.org/aboutJava/communityprocess/final/jsr330/index.html), there is no JSR 299 or JSR 346 support in Spring.